# Colour spiral not working in XNA

Tags: c#, colors, xna, drawing, xna-4.0

I am making a simple process which will create a colour changing spiral so I can test a range of variables and learn some C#. However, though I can not find a problem in the code, when I debug it, I am returned with a blank blue screen. Can any one find the problem. Here is all the code containing the variables needed for the ball point:

```
    Vector2 Tripos;
    List<Color> Tricol;
    List<Vector2> datatripos;
    List<int> count;
    Color currentcol;
    float Tri_angle;
    float Triscale;
    int Tri_speed;
    int screenwidth;
    int screenheight;
    int addtocount;
    Texture2D Ball;
    int colourchangespeed;

 protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.

        Tripos = new Vector2(screenwidth / 2, screenheight / 2);
        Triscale = 1;
        Tri_angle = 1;
        Tri_speed = 1;
        colourchangespeed = 1;
        Ball = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ball");
        currentcol = new Color(0, 0, 0);
        addtocount = 0;
        datatripos = new List<Vector2>();
        Tricol = new List<Color>();
    }
```

This is called by the update method:

```
        private void Posgen()
    {

        Tripos.X += (float)Math.Sin(MathHelper.ToRadians(Tri_angle))*Tri_speed;
        Tripos.Y += (float)Math.Cos(MathHelper.ToRadians(Tri_angle))*Tri_speed;
        Tri_angle++;
    }
    private void colchanger()
    {
        currentcol.R += (byte)colourchangespeed;
        if (currentcol.R == 255)
        {
            currentcol.R = 0;
            currentcol.G += (byte)colourchangespeed;
        }
        if (currentcol.G == 255)
        {
            currentcol.G = 0;
            currentcol.B += (byte)colourchangespeed;
        }
        if (currentcol.B == 255)
        {
            currentcol.B = 0;
        }
    }
    private void dataadd()
    {
        addtocount++;
        Tricol.Add(currentcol);
        datatripos.Add(Tripos);
        count.Add(addtocount);
    }
```

Called by the draw method:

```
    private void drawtri()
    {
        foreach (Vector2 data in datatripos)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(Ball, data, null, currentcol, 0, new Vector2(5, 5), Triscale, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
        }
    }
```

If you want the full code ask in advance. There are some variables I don't use but I intend to use for later so ignore these.

Thanks in advance.

Yours Mona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you are calling `dataadd()`.

As a precaution, `colourchangespeed` should be declared as a byte rather than as an `int` because you're only casting to a byte anyway. When checking you colour values, the current value should be compared as `>= 255` in the case that `colourchangespeed` is not 1.

A tip to writing good questions: Remove everything that's unrelated. Everything.